# Selenium Gmail login password field

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, gmail

I am trying to login Gmail using selenium web driver. The problem I am facing is that I am not able to set the password in the input box.

Here is the generated error message:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot focus element.

Here is my code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
    driver.navigate().to("http://www.gmail.com");
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#identifierId")).sendKeys("********@gmail.com"); 
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#identifierNext")).click();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#password")));

    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#password")).sendKeys("********"); 
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#passwordNext")).click();
    driver.close();
    driver.quit();
}
```

Comment: Can you share the full error message? Your error message shows that cannot focus element, but which element? is it password field or any other field?

Comment: try `By.cssSelector("input[type=password]")` instead. It looks like you're grabbing the wrong element. If that works I'll post as an answer. Although you might also be running into a situation where the element is visible, but it's not quite ready to be interacted with as well.

Comment: @mrfreester By.cssSelector("input[type=password]")  this does not work.

Comment: @AuroSarma --------                                                                     
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot focus element
  (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.32.498550 (9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c5810906a),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: @Meghabagri do you get the same error message? I would expect the **cannot focus element** error for the `#password` selector, but not `input[type=password]`. To verify it's not a wait issue, you can also put a Sleep for 5 seconds right before you try to call `sendKeys` on the password field. If that works, then you are waiting for the wrong condition.

Comment: @mrfreester thank you so much, It worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a combination of a wait issue and selecting the wrong element.

Try changing your selector in your sendKeys as follows:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type=password]")).sendKeys("********");
```

If that still doesn't work, you could try a different wait condition before that call, such as:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input[type=password]")));
```

You might need to do some experiments to find the right wait condition, but doing both of those things should get you what you need. :)

Answer (score 1):

Wait until an element becomes clickable. Here is how you can do this.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input[type=password]"));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type=password]")).sendKeys("your password");
```

Answer (score 0):

The cssSelector of the element you are trying to use is not right.

I would suggest to use dynamically generated xpath and/or cssSelector all the time.

In the code below, I used dynamically generated xpath for email Id and cssSelector for password. Try this and it works fine.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "Y:\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
    driver.navigate().to("http://www.gmail.com");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='email']")).sendKeys("*********@gmail.com"); 
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#identifierNext")).click();

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("input[type=password]")));

    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type=password]")).sendKeys("*********"); 
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#passwordNext")).click();
    driver.quit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can also use the name atribute here, like this**:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("********");
```

I think everything is solved, however I would like **to clarify why it was not working**:

**To enter the email**, You used an id and it worked fine, because the id `identifierId` is one of the attribute of the filed you are filling.

**To enter the password**, you cannot use `password` as an id because the field you are trying to fill has no id among its attributes. The id `password` exists, but it embraces a larger amount of WebElement. **In fact you are localizing an id which contains this field among other WebElements**, hence the error message telling you **it is unable to focus**

you can either use xpath, such as

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='password']")).sendKeys("********");
```

or css selector such as:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type=password]")).sendKeys("********");
```

but you cannot access this field using an ID.

I tried all those three solutions and they worked.
Regarding the possible waiting issue, do not hesitate to use wrappers with waiter around `findElement` method, it can help a lot. However, I think it was not the main issue here.